# Acessing overloaded function from an Abstract Base class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, derived-class, abstract-base-class

I know this question has been asked before in some form. But I am still confused.

Suppose I have two classes.

```
class A{
public:
 void foo(int a, int b);
protected:
 virtual void foo(int a) = 0;
}

class B : public class A{
void foo(int a);
}
```

Now if I want to make the visibility of the non virtual function in class A public in class B .... how do I do that?? ... In other words currently I am able to call the non virtual function in this manner

```
B b;
b.A::foo(3, 5);
```

and I want to avoid this ^

and the solution of putting this

```
using A::foo;
```

in public B refers the virtual function in A .... not the non-virtual function ... so I think that is not the solution.

Comment: `using A::foo; `refers to all foo in A. Choose an other name for one function.

Comment: Fix your design. Using the same name for 2 different functions and types thereof is the real problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A{
public:
  void foo(int a, int b);
protected:
  virtual void foo(int a) = 0;
};

class B : public A{
public:
  using A::foo;
protected:
  void foo(int a);
};

void f()
{
  B b;
  b.foo(1,2);  // OK
  b.foo(3);    //  error: ‘virtual void B::foo(int)’ is protected within this context
}
```

works as expcted. foo with two parameters is callable, foo with one not.